# How to write the word "C++" in Jira, avoiding its automatic formatting?

Tags: formatting, jira

How can I write the word "C++" in a Jira comment?

I tried C++, "C++", [C++], {{C++}}, {C plus plus} without success. It always gets reformatted, and all I get is C+

Comment: Which version of Jira you use? Because in v8.3.1 it's doesn't reproduce.

Comment: It is JIRA v7.4.0. And it does not seem to happen regularly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Jira Comment :**

I tried with your suggested words like C++, "C++", [C++], {{C++}} and {C plus plus} in Jira Andropid App version(v35.0.363) and Web App also.

**It is working fine and i got results such as below...**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if Jira thinks that you try to use the +inserted+ text effect, ref. https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=texteffects

Special characters can be escaped by preceding them with backslash, ref. https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=miscellaneous